# Change Background Colour Along a Gradient as User Scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I'm trying to get the background colour of the page to change on the gradient between black and white as the user scrolls. The colour will depend on where the user is currently scrolled to on the page if that makes sense? Here's some code I have already however the only problem with it is that when the user hasn't scrolled anywhere the webpage is not black.

```js
function scroll(){
 var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
 var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
 var color = Math.round(((body.scrollTop + html.offsetHeight) / height) * 255);
 body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color+","+color+","+color+")";
}
```

```css
html{
 height: 100%;
}
body{
 height: 200%;
 background: rgb(126,126,126);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <body onscroll="scroll()">
    <script src="assets/JS/ScrollEffect.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `html.scrollTop` instead of `body.scrollTop`.
That's because the html element becomes scrollable. The `body` element with 200% height overflows `html` with 100% height, which is the viewport height.

Body does not scroll here, so you always get `body.scrollTop = 0`.
But html does scroll, so you have to use `html.scrollTop`.

The elements `body` and `html` sometimes act as if they are one element. That's the case for scrolling behaviour. But sometimes they act as if they are two separate elements. That's the cases in styling with CSS.

To get from black to white (not grey to white), you have to change `var height = html.scrollHeight - html.clientHeight;` and `var color = Math.round((html.scrollTop / height) * 255);`

To make it work in IE you need to add:
`<html onscroll="scroll()">`

If you can, you should use jquery though (like Kushtrim suggested).

```js
function scroll(){
 var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
 var height = html.scrollHeight - html.clientHeight;
 var color = Math.round((html.scrollTop / height) * 255);
 body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color+","+color+","+color+")";
}
```

```css
html{
 height: 100%;
}
body{
 height: 200%;
 background: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" onscroll="scroll()">

  <body onscroll="scroll()">
    <script src="assets/JS/ScrollEffect.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I saw a change request to change `var color = Math.round((html.scrollTop / height) * 255);` to use `body.scrollTop` instead of `html.scrollTop`. If you change that, the example won't work any more.

Comment: I removed the statement about using body.scrollTop if there is content inside body and styling is overflow: scroll because I think that does not work. It seems you always have to get the scrolling information from the html element. Instead I added a paragraph mentioning the confusing behviour of html and body.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(window).height();

  var scrolledArea = (s / (d - c));
  $("div").css("opacity", scrolledArea);
})
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

div{
  height: 500vh;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, read more [here](https://codepen.io/kapz/pen/hxmpb)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.container .overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 160, 227, 0.5) 0%, rgba(176, 203, 31, 0.5) 50%, rgba(239, 127, 26, 0.5) 100%);
}
.container .slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.secs {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.secs .inside {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.secs.first {
  text-align: center;
}
.secs.first h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999,2px 2px 1px #999,3px 3px 1px #999,4px 4px 1px #999;
  transform: translate(-50%, -155%);
  z-index: 10;
}
.secs.first .inside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.secs.first .bar {
  width: 80px;
  height: 350px;
  opacity: 0.54;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background: #fff;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(1) {
  background: #00a0e3;
  animation: bars 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(130px);
  background: #00a0e3;
  animation: bars1 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(30px);
  background: #b0cb1f;
  animation: bars2 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateY(80px);
  background: #b0cb1f;
  animation: bars3 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  background: #ef7f1a;
  animation: bars4 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translateY(135px);
  background: #ef7f1a;
  animation: bars5 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translateY(55px);
  background: #e31e24;
  animation: bars6 5s infinite;
}
.secs.first .bar:nth-child(8) {
  background: #e31e24;
  animation: bars7 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes bars {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(130px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(130px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(130px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(135px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(135px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(55px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(55px);
  }
}
@keyframes bars7 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(120px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='overlay'>
    <div class='slide secs first'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```